# How to perform convolution separately on the input channels?

Tags: tensorflow

Is it possible to perform convolution on the input channels separately? As there are two input channels having depth 2. If I set filter as`[2,2,1,1]` it gives me error. Then how can I perform convolution separately on the two input channels?

```
input = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1,4,4,2]))
filter = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2,2,2,1]))
op = tf.nn.conv2d(input, filter, strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')
```

Comment: Does ``tf.slice`` work for your problem?  e.g. ``input_1 = tf.slice(input, [0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 4, 4, 1])``, then do the ``conv2d``.

Comment: Yes its working. Thanks

Comment: If I split them does it change the number of parameters? and if I split them perform convolution separately and then join them what will be the effect?

Comment: Yes, it reduces the number of parameters. Didn't you want this, performing convolution separately on the two input channels? Or I misunderstood your question?

Comment: yes i want to perform convolution separately.But I don't know that what will be the effect. What if I perform convolution separately and then then I combine them at the end.

Comment: Can you please explain how parameters will reduce? Although I split them but I have to apply convolution on both channels

Comment: When I perform convolution on two filters when they were together,they share the same weights.  But when I split them weights will be different  so the no of parameter increases

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. Each output channel (filter) of convolution operates on all input channels, while your desired operation performs on only one input channel for each filter. They are different. But the no of parameters depends on how many filters you want to output. In my opinion, convolution will give richer information than your operation because it considers all input channels and it weights all of them. It's like that it can reach any point within a square but your way can only reach the points on two sides. Maybe this doesn't respond your question but hope it helps.

Comment: Have I answered your question?

Answer (score 1):

> How to perform convolution separately on the input channels?

`tf.nn.depthwise_conv2d`

"applies a different filter to each input channel (expanding from 1 channel to channel_multiplier channels for each), then concatenates the results together."